# Find the truth value of... empty set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

Here is my Discrete Math question

> Let $P(n)$ denote the statement "$n$ is prime." Find the truth value of "very $n$ in empty set is a prime number". And explain your answer.

I understand every $n$ in empty set is NOT a prime number. And **what does it mean by "Find the truth value of" in this question?**

Professor gave me this hint but I don't understand.

> Hey this is a hint. What is the truth value of NOT every $n$ in empty set is a prime number?

Comment: Also I'm having trouble adding Latex equation in this forum. Can anyone please leave a comment how to put the equation from LaTeX equation Editor

Comment: It is true that all numbers in $\varnothing$ are prime, because there exist no non-prime numbers in $\varnothing$.

Comment: Here is a link to the tutorial of mathjax. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference
To my knowledge using latex is not possible, however mathjax is fairly similar and also straightforward

Comment: @Nilknarf Um I think that's correct. But I think it's not answering the question of... "Find the truth value of ~, and explain your answer"

Comment: Is your question just what "truth value" means, or is it something else?

Comment: @EricWofsey My bad. I just added "Explain your answer" after the question. Does it help??

Comment: I don't know what that response has to do with what I asked...

Comment: @EricWofsey Oh you are talking about "my question in this forum". I was confused. OK my question is what "truth value" means. Why is he asking me about "truth value". Should I say `There doesn't exist n in empty set such that n is prime`?

Comment: Also, can you give us the literal, exact phrasing of the problem you are trying to solve?  The version you have written is ungrammatical and does not literally make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement "for all $x\in S, P(x)$" is *true if $S=\emptyset$, no matter what the proposition $P$ is*.

So, every integer in $\emptyset$ is prime, as well as every integer in $\emptyset$ is composite, as well as every integer in $\emptyset$ is equal to itself, and to $\pi$, and every unicorn in $\emptyset$ is rainbow-coloured. Some of those statements sound nonsensical, but are nevertheless true.

This is because the opposite of "for all $x\in S, P(x)$" is "there exists $x\in S$ such that $\lnot P(x)$". This is obviously false if $S=\emptyset$, because there *doesn't exist an $x\in\emptyset$ at all*, let alone such $x$ for which $\lnot P(x)$ would be true.

Comment: Uhmm what if P is quadrant?

Comment: 1/o will be undefined and it can possibly make the statement truth?

Comment: @JohnBaek Sorry, what do you call a "quadrant"? Also, what is "o" in the denominator? Note there is no $o\in\emptyset$.

Comment: Oh I meant, "rational number: Q". a/b while b!=0.

Comment: That is fine. Every number in $\emptyset$ is rational; as you know, $\emptyset\subseteq\mathbb Q$.

Comment: I don't understand. umm

Comment: The empty set is a subset of any set $S$. This follows from the fact that for $P(x)$ you can take $x\in S$.

Comment: So it makes sense that "These exists a n in emptyset, such that n is not national number" is FALSE.???

Comment: Exactly. It is false because you cannot even find any $n\in\emptyset$, let alone find such $n$ that is not rational.

Comment: thanks it makes sense. have a good day

Answer (score 2):

To find the truth value of a statement is to discover whether the statement is true or false. So suppose "for all $n$ in $\varnothing$, $n$ is prime" is false. Then there must be an $n$ in $\varnothing$ which is not prime. Can you point me to such an $n$?

Comment: I don't understand why you are questioning which n to me. Could you add more detail so that I can understand your answer?

Comment: @JohnBaek - I modified the question a bit.

Comment: I can't find any n from empty set because it's literally empty set. Should I answer it like `There doesn't exist n in empty set such that n is prime`? Thanks

Comment: @JohnBaek - So, if there is no $n$ in $\varnothing$ which is not prime, then all $n$ in $\varnothing$ are prime, that is, the statement you were inquired about is true.

Comment: One more question. what if it's asking n is quadrant number? (a over b). Does it same true like this solution?

Comment: @JohnBaek - For any statement $P$, $P(n) $ is true for all $n$ in $\varnothing$.

Comment: I meant what if the P(n) is Q(n)? Q(n) is rational number. a/b. what if b is 0??

Answer (score 2):

The "truth value" of a statement is just whether it is true or false.  So the problem is asking you to determine whether the statement is true or false.

Comment: Thanks it helped! voted up :)

Comment: One more question. what if it's asking n is quadrant number? (a over b). Does it same true like this solution?

Answer (score 2):

"Let P(n) denote the statement n is prime" is a statement which does not appear other times in the premise nor in the question, so we will totally ignore it.

"for all n in empty set, n is prime number" is a statement which does not depend by n, so it could be true or false. In this case, it's true because you are checking a property over the empty set (google: vacuous truth).

Your professor hint makes sense, because it makes the logic way more evident. The negation of "for all n in empty set, n is prime number" is

"NOT for all n in empty set, n is prime number"

which is equivalent to

"exists an n in empty set, n is NOT prime number".

This is evidently false, because it doesn't exist any element in the empty set, with or without the stated property.

Comment: Thanks for very concrete answer. Voted up :)

Comment: One more question. what if it's asking n is quadrant number? (a over b). Does it same true like this solution?